# data.indexOf is not a function error in [tabulator]

Tags: javascript, html, tabulator

data.indexOf is not a function error in Tabulator JavaScript Library.

Complete error message:

```
[Error] TypeError: data.indexOf is not a function. (In 'data.indexOf("{")', 'data.indexOf' is undefined)
    load (tabulator.js:6075)
    _loadInitialData (tabulator.js:7971)
    _create (tabulator.js:7841)
    (anonieme functie) (tabulator.js:7756)
```

And warning:

```
Table Not Initialized - Calling the redraw function before the table is initialized may result in inconsistent behavior, Please wait for the `tableBuilt` event before calling this function
```

I used the setup as described in the doc, browser based so tabulator.js and tabulator.css in the location that is in the html. Nothing else done.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tabulator.css">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tabulator.css.map"> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script defer src="js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
        <script defer src="js/crud.js"></script>
        <script defer src="js/data.js"></script>
        <script defer src="js/assess.js"></script>
        <title>DMMA</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main id="home">
            <h1 class="center-text dark-blue-text">Datamanagement Maturity Assessment</h1>
            <div id="entree" class="container"></div>
            <div class="output container"></div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

My javascript in assess.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function() {
  
  // the assObj is the data of assessment objects I want to retrieve
  const assObj = new dataProvider;
 
  // Use Tabulator
  assObj.get('api.php/records/AssmntPlusObjects')

    // .then(async dataArray => displayRecords(dta, false))   // Works!
    .then(dataArray => {
      let table = new Tabulator("#entree", {
        data: dataArray,
        autoColumns: true
      })
    })
    .catch(err => displayError(err, null))
});
```

The **assObj.get** goes to a fetch class that gets the data from a MySQL database that gets the data via a PHP generic API. That all works.
The data array with objects is transformed to JavaScript object OK. The Tabulator gives the above error.

The site is on an internet provider host, I don't want to run another MySQL locally.

Any suggestions? Setup wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `dataArray` before you construct the Tabulator instance?

Comment: debug and find out what dataArray is. `console.log(typeof dataArray, dataArray);`

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reaction. this is dataArray:

Comment: [Log] dataArray :>>  (assess.js, line 13)
Object

records: [Object, Object, Object, Object] (4)

Object prototype

Comment: An array with 4 record objects. [Log] dataArray :>>  (assess.js, line 13)
Object

records: Array (4)
0 {id: 1, asm_Name: "DMMA Scan", asm_Language: "Nederlands", periode_van: "2023-01-09", periode_tm: null, …}
1 {id: 2, asm_Name: "DMMA Scan", asm_Language: "Engels", periode_van: "2023-01-03", periode_tm: null, …}
2 {id: 3, asm_Name: "Data Management", asm_Language: "Nederlands", periode_van: "2023-01-03", periode_tm: null, …}
3 {id: 4, asm_Name: "Data Management", asm_Language: "Engels", periode_van: "2023-01-03", periode_tm: null, …}

Array prototype

Object prototype

Answer (score 1):

Found the culprit! I needed get to the records in dataArray with

```
data: dataArray.records,
```

That's it!

I found that amazing because in a custom table function I built with the data (the displayRecords(dataArray, false)) it just worked without the .records property.

Thanks for putting me on the track of the contents of the dataArray.

Answer (score 0):

`dataArray` is either empty or undefined. Check by `console.log(dataArray)`